# OpenGeo/Geoserver: can I have a store that access more than one PostGIS schema?

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I have an existing PostGIS database that I use with QGIS.  I am now looking at options for getting some of this data up on the web. Hence OpenGeo.

I have Geoserver installed and running and have succeeded in loading a simple layer from my PostGIS database.  My current problem is that in QGIS/PostGIS I have used the base schema for my geometry tables and put all the tables relating to my layers into the layers schema.  I build my layer using sql.

When I create a new 'store' in geoserver I am forced to specify a single schema within the database so this breaks my modus operandi that I use in QGIS.

I am also struggling to figure out how to define "SQL Views" and whether or not these are dependent on 'stores' or whether there is some other mechanism that will allow me to do arbitrarily complex SQL queries on the database.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can't do a view across schema but wait and see if anyone else has a more definitive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot have a store that addresses more than one schema. You can get stores to share a database connection pool if you use JNDI configuration, but that's about as far as it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the definitive answer.  Reorganising my database is no big deal and will actually simplify thing.